# Merging Database tables Unique fields issue

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, ms-access

I've got a program (that I can't alter, It is a music application written by some other developer) which uses a couple of access 97' databases. One of those databases is a "Playlists" database, with 2 tables "PlaylistNames" and "PlaylistSongs".

"PlaylistNames" table has an AutoIncrement, Unique, PrimaryKey "autoID" column of type long, a "PlaylistName" string column which holds the name of each Playlist and a "isServerPlaylist" bool column which defines whether the playlist is created by the user or was sent from the server.

"PlaylistSongs" table has a AutoIncrement, Unique, PrimaryKey "autoID" column, a "PlaylistID" column which is a ForeignKey pointing to the previous table "autoID" field and a "TrackID" column ForeignKey to another table which holds the songs informations.

This is how the records in the 2 tables look like:

"PlaylistNames"

autoID:01  PlaylistName:Rock  isServerPlaylist:True

autoID:02  PlaylistName:Pop   isServerPlaylist:True

"PlaylistSongs"

autoID:01  PlaylistID:01  TrackID:100

autoID:02  PlaylistID:01  TrackID:101

autoID:03  PlaylistID:01  TrackID:102

autoID:04  PlaylistID:02  TrackID:103

autoID:05  PlaylistID:02  TrackID:104

autoID:06  PlaylistID:02  TrackID:105

which means that there are 2 current playlists, Rock and Pop and each consists of 3 tracks.

Now, there is a client and server side copy of the databases. The client database has the server's copy of playlists plus any playlist that a client would add/create. The playlists on the server side are also updated.

Lets say the server playlists are those 2 Rock and Pop. If the user adds/creates a new playlist, a new record on the PlaylistNames table will be added on the client database with autoID = 03, a playlistName that the client will choose and the isServerPlaylist field = false. In the PlaylistSongs table will be added as many records as the songs that the client will choose to add in the playlist. The playlistID column will be 03.

The server also updates its playlists so, with an update on the server I might add/create an new playlist which will have in the PlaylistNames table autoID = 03, a playlist name that I will choose and isServerSide column set to true.

What I want to do is merge those playlists, in a way that when new playlists are added on the server side and when a client has created his own playlists the AutoID primary key column of the merged PlaylistNames table will have unique values. Thats where I'm stuck. Could you guys point a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the serverside processing is out of your reach? (i.e. merging the two playlists?)

In that case, I would suggest that, when your user is creating a playlist offline, it automatically checks if there already is a similar playlist on the server.
From there on, you can either download the existing serverplaylist, then add on to it. Or you could also just check what the highest ID is on that server playlist and make sure your offline playlist starts at (maximumIDserverside +1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, at the moment there is no merging of the playlists databases due to that issue, the only update is happening on the songs and it is a hard coded update done by checking if the 2 databases have different count of records. If so the missing songs in the clients database are downloaded and the tables  are dropped and recreated with the new entries. There's a problem with this method though, the application is a continious music player for coffeshops bars etc.  The drop and recreation of the tables could cause the player to stop if it happens simultaneously

Comment: with a song mix (next song in the player tries to play when the database
is dropped). The company didnt experience such a problem so far, drop and recreation takes a second aprox. but it is not the best way to do it. The problem is that 
the playlists are created/added inside the application the other developer created and the databases update from that application as well, which means I can't 
"play" with the autoIncrement step on any of the tables.I'm gonna try and merge both tables to one table in a way that I will have the PlaylistSongs table data 
in the same record with the Playlist

Comment: they belong. Then split the data again in 2 tables.

Comment: Right, what I last said isn't making much sense because the number of playlists songs isn't static. A playlist could have 20 songs and another one could have less or more, so I can't really know how many columns to add to the tmp table that will hold all the data from the 2 tables. It could work, but its not the best solution. Problems could arise when the client will try to add more songs in a playlist than the columns I have created in the temp table to hold the songs of each playlist. I'll try it tomorrow. this is a temporary solution anyway, I'm developing the new solution for the company

Comment: Why are you using columns to add songs to a playlist? I would suggest having a 1-* relationship between playlists ands songs, and add the ID of the playlist the song belongs to in the songs table. That way, you can add as many songs as you like. More songs = more rows, not columns.

Comment: Do you mean one-to-many relationship? Yeah, thats a better way, I'm gonna try that.

Answer (score 0):

It's more simple. Add to primary key the isServerPlaylist field and play.

Comment: κρίμα (=pity). How can this happen?

Comment: Sorry I might have missunderstood what you suggested. What do you mean by add to primary key another field? Do you mean I should set isServerSide as the primary key?

Comment: No. Your primary key should be audioID and isServerPlaylist (both of them)

Comment: Right, database newbie here. I didn't know I could set 2 fields as one primary key. I don't understand how would this help. Could you explain it?

Comment: You will have pairs of audioID and isServerPlaylist as [1, YES] and [1, NO]. In other words each audioID can exist on a database two times.

Comment: Cool, thanks for making that clear. Thats not what I need thought. The program that uses the databases won't be able to read them like that.